# Laravel 5.1 auth attempt with extra parameters using default auth controller and middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, roles

How to override Laravel 5.1 auth attempt with extra parameters using default auth controller and middleware?
suppose I have an extra field with status `=active` or `inactive`.
How can I write that attempt method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) you can pass an array of variables, with their keys being the columns you want to verify the values against in the database.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $attempt = Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $request->get('email'), 
            'password' => $request->get('password'), 
            'active' => $request->get('active')
        ]);

        if ($attempt) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please read the bounty details where It is asked to have an authorization table etc. This answer would have been a too easy bounty don't you think?

Comment: @davejal Your bounty specification doesn't make any sense in the context of the question asked. The question is about authentication logging in.

Comment: @davejal Yes, to provide more clarity as it isn't very clear what you want.

Comment: I will ask to edit the question, but the part I added was authorization. Having a table to add role based privileges to users.

Comment: I agree with Enijar. The specified bounty should have been asked as a completely separate question and should not have been added to this existing question.

Comment: role-based privillige for laravel, you could use [zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) or many other package. People already code for that.

Comment: then I will go ahead and award it

Comment: I have to wait 10 more hours, sorry

Comment: really nice explanation